# Why my command line instruction doesn't eject the cd?

Tags: java, command-line, cd-rom, cd-burning

In a program I burn a Cd using ISO Writer, due to this [link](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/ISOWriter.htm) my code should eject the cd after write because of -e command line, it burns to the cd but doesn't eject it after write, I don't know what's the problem?

```
//Library that use to create iso file
File mkisofs = new File("lib/cdrtools/mkisofs.exe");

//The root of file that we want to write on DVD
File source = new File(new ProductUtil().getProductDir()+ "\\output\\Autorun");

//Destination that the iso file will be save on it.
File destination = source.getParentFile();

//Library that use to write iso file
File isoWriter = new File("lib/isowriter/ISOWriter.exe");


String command = mkisofs.getPath()+" -UDF -o \'"+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\' \'"+source.getAbsolutePath()+"\'";
Process createIso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(createIso.getErrorStream()));

String line = "";
String all = "";

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    all += line+"\r\n";
}

if(createIso.waitFor() != 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, all,"Error on creating ISO file: ("+createIso.waitFor()+")",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}

command = isoWriter.getPath()+" -s 16 -e  \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";
System.out.println(command);
Process writeIso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

It is the error i get when adding the drive's name in this format:

```
command = isoWriter.getPath()+" f: -s 16 -e  \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";
```

[image]

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder which provides better way to form command to be executed.

Comment: I don't know anything about it, would you please give more lead how should i do that? @SachinGorade

Comment: Try looking up the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it has an example in the introduction.

Comment: Example: ISOWrite -r e: -e C:\Data\image.iso

Use recordable drive E:, eject after completion. Burns c:\data\image.iso

Comment: I understand this example but why my code doesn't work even it uses -e ? @SantoshShinde

Comment: before -e use recordable drive

Comment: how is it that it burns on the cd in my code without writing the drive's name? and another thing is that I want my code be needless to the drive's name. @SantoshShinde

Comment: so better way use process builder

Comment: ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "your coomand");
      builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
      Process p = builder.start();

Comment: In your command you must give your current cd drive which you operate

Comment: @user333 last error screen shows that drive does not contain recordable drive. Check whether you are specifying correct drive letter.

Comment: but my cd drive's name is f! @SachinGorade

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forming command using + operator you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
//  Library that use to create iso file
                File mkisofs = new File("lib/cdrtools/mkisofs.exe");
                //  The root of file that we want to write on DVD
                File source = new File(new ProductUtil().getProductDir()+ "\\output\\Autorun");
                //  Destination that the iso file will be save on it.
                File destination = source.getParentFile();
                //  Library that use to write iso file
                File isoWriter = new File("lib/isowriter/ISOWriter.exe");
                String command[] = {mkisofs.getPath(), "-UDF", "-o", destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso", source.getAbsolutePath() };
                 Process createIso = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(createIso.getErrorStream()));
            String line = "";
            String all = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                all += line+"\r\n";
            }
            if(createIso.waitFor() != 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, all,"Error on creating ISO file: ("+createIso.waitFor()+")",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return null;
            }
            command = {isoWriter.getPath(), "-s", "16", "E:", "-e",  destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso"};
            System.out.println(command);
            Process writeIso = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

I do not know anything about the library you are using but as per @SantoshShinde I have added drive letter into arguments. You can try skipping it as well to check whether it works.

Comment: I added the error when using either your code or this one in my question: command = isoWriter.getPath()+" -s 16 -e  \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";

Answer (score 0):

Try to this by replacing follwing code in your code

```
            command = isoWriter.getPath()+" -s 16 -e  \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";
            System.out.println(command);
            Process writeIso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

By ..

```
         command = isoburn.exe /q D: \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";
         ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
         builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
         Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: refer this  http://tweaks.com/windows/48619/how-to-burn-cd-and-dvd-images-iso-files-from-the-command-line/

Comment: I added the error i get using your code to my question

Comment: you need to add your recordable drive is F in your command  ,      command = isoWriter.getPath()+" -s 16 f: -e  \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\"";

Comment: I added the drive' name and there is an erro which I added it in my question!

Comment: please read this , may be this is useful for you http://superuser.com/questions/712271/is-it-possible-to-burn-an-iso-image-to-a-dvd-using-cmd-in-windows-7-or-8

Comment: use this command  ,, command = isoburn.exe /q D: \""+destination.getAbsolutePath()+"\\cd.iso\""     here D: is [the CD/DVD writing drive]